# remove node in doubly linked class in C++

Tags: c++, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm developing a doubly linked list class that uses a Node class in C++.

I'm trying to make a remove function that deletes the desired node if it exist.

But if the value is greater than `currentPrt` it just exits without doing anything, and if it is less, it deletes the node and the program gets into an endless loop of printing weird values.

Code of Node class:

```
// Node.h

class Node {
public:

    explicit Node(int data = 0, Node *nextPtr = nullptr, Node *beforePtr = nullptr);

    int getData() const;

    void setData(int data);

    Node *getNextPtr() const;

    void setNextPtr(Node *nextPtr);

    Node *getBeforePtr() const;

    void setBeforePtr(Node *beforePtr);

    void print() const;

private:
    int data;
    Node *nextPtr;
    Node *beforePtr;


};
```

```
// Node.cpp

Node::Node(int data, Node *nextPtr, Node *beforePtr) : data(data), nextPtr(nextPtr), beforePtr(beforePtr) {}

int Node::getData() const {
    return data;
}

void Node::setData(int data) {
    Node::data = data;
}

Node *Node::getNextPtr() const {
    return nextPtr;
}

void Node::setNextPtr(Node *nextPtr) {
    Node::nextPtr = nextPtr;
}

Node *Node::getBeforePtr() const {
    return beforePtr;
}

void Node::setBeforePtr(Node *beforePtr) {
    Node::beforePtr = beforePtr;
}

void Node::print() const {

    cout << getData() << endl;

}
```

```
// MyList.h

class MyList {

public:
    MyList(Node *currentPrt = nullptr);

    void insert(int value);

    void print() const;


private:
    Node *currentPrt;

};
```

```
// MyList.cpp

MyList::MyList(){
    currentPrt = nullptr;
}

void MyList::insert(int value) {

    if(currentPrt == nullptr){
        currentPrt = new Node;
        currentPrt->setData(value);
        currentPrt->setNextPtr(nullptr);
        currentPrt->setBeforePtr(nullptr);

    }
    else{
        if(value > currentPrt->getData()){
            while (currentPrt->getNextPtr() != nullptr && currentPrt->getNextPtr()->getData() < value){
                currentPrt = currentPrt->getNextPtr();
            }

            Node *newPtr = new Node(value);
            newPtr->setNextPtr(currentPrt->getNextPtr());
            if (currentPrt->getNextPtr() != nullptr) // <---
                currentPrt->getNextPtr()->setBeforePtr(newPtr); // <---
            currentPrt->setNextPtr(newPtr);
            newPtr->setBeforePtr(currentPrt);
        }
        else{
            while (currentPrt->getBeforePtr() != nullptr && currentPrt->getBeforePtr()->getData() > value){
                currentPrt = currentPrt->getBeforePtr();
            }
            Node *newPtr = new Node(value);
            if (currentPrt->getBeforePtr() != nullptr){
                currentPrt = currentPrt->getBeforePtr();
                newPtr->setNextPtr(currentPrt->getNextPtr());
                currentPrt->getNextPtr()->setBeforePtr(newPtr); // <---
                currentPrt->setNextPtr(newPtr);
                newPtr->setBeforePtr(currentPrt);
            }
            else{
                currentPrt->setBeforePtr(newPtr);
                newPtr->setNextPtr(currentPrt);
            }
        }
    }




}

void MyList::remove(int value) {

    if (currentPrt != nullptr){
        if(value > currentPrt->getData()){
            while (currentPrt->getNextPtr() != nullptr && currentPrt->getBeforePtr()->getData() > value){
                currentPrt = currentPrt->getNextPtr();
            }
            if (currentPrt->getNextPtr()->getData() == value){
                delete currentPrt->getNextPtr();
            }
        }
        else{
            while (currentPrt->getBeforePtr() != nullptr && currentPrt->getBeforePtr()->getData() > value){
                currentPrt = currentPrt->getBeforePtr();
            }
            if (currentPrt->getBeforePtr()->getData() == value){
                delete currentPrt->getBeforePtr();
            }
        }
    }

}

void MyList::print() const {
    Node *ptr;
    ptr = currentPrt;
    while(ptr->getNextPtr() != nullptr){
        ptr = ptr->getNextPtr();
    }
    for (ptr; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->getBeforePtr()){
        cout << ptr->getData() << endl;
    }

}
```

Main:

```
    MyList test;
    test.insert(5);
    test.insert(3);
    test.insert(7);
    test.insert(6);
    test.printAscending();
    std::cout<<endl;
    test.remove(7); // doesn't work but doesn't cause infinit print
    test.remove(5); // doesn't work but doesn't cause infinit print
    test.remove(6); // causes infinit prints
    test.remove(3); // causes infinit prints
    test.printAscending();
```

Ouput of only remove(5), remove(7):

```
3
5
6
7

3
5
6
7
```

if I put `remove(6)`, (or 3), it gets into and endless print of numbers like this:

```
2109940880
2109365888
2109348064
2109342032
```

What is wrong with my `remove` implementation?

Comment: You should add driver code that creates a list, calls the remove method and demonstrates the issue. Also provide the information you got from debugging.

Comment: @trincot, I edited the post with test list and output

Comment: I voted to reopen your question. Let's see...

Comment: No, that will not be appreciated by the community and will lead to downvotes. I edited your question more... But still you should focus on the version of the main code that produces the problem. Now you have presented a sequence that seems to work, and then say something about replacing a call, ... but that is not clear. Better present the **smallest** possible sequence of calls that produces the problem, and only that.

Comment: So you mean only do calls to the remove that causes the problem and shrink the test list right?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly.

Comment: Just edited it. Does it look better?

Comment: Yes, this looks better. But now it will take some time to get it reopened

Comment: What's wrong with my code [is not a real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). You should make an effort to [debug your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). You'll have a much better chance to write a better question and get more meaningful answers.

Comment: @Evg, it is clear what they ask. The "what's wrong" comes in a context of a clear question of where the desired behaviour is known, the wrong behaviour is demonstrated, and the asker has provided their attempt. It might not be a good attempt, and effort may be lacking, but all that is relative. This question is narrow enough, and can be answered.

Comment: @trincot There is no specific question about posted code, it is not clear what kind of difficulties OP has and what kind of help OP needs. "What's wrong with my code" together with no demonstrated debugging effort is not a good question for SO and we should not encourage people to post such questions. The link above clearly explains why.

Comment: @Evg, I will not agree, but I'm currently trying a new method an will update this question if it still didn't work

Comment: @trincot, I appreciate your help and effort to reopen the question

Comment: @trincot found the issue within my question and gave me the answer. However I didn't use his exact code, I only needed the concept to know what I did wrong.

Comment: *and that I'm just here for the answer without trying* - Then let me ask you why you shared no details about your attempts? We don't have a crystal ball and can only see what you shared with us in your question. The only thing that I see right now is a bunch of code and the question "what's wrong with it".

Comment: If you actually look at the code, you can see a REMOVE function and the tests of the REMOVE function with its outputs. So I don't know why you're arguing right now. the extra code is to make others understand that I made my own Node class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not execute `delete` on a node that is still in the linked list. First you need to rewire any references **to** it. That is to say, the node before should have its `nextPtr` redirected to the node after the one that is to be deleted, and that node should have its `beforePtr` redirected as well.

Also, your code deletes the *next* node when it has found the matching value, and not that node itself. Moreover, there is no provision to delete more nodes in case the value occurs in more than one node.

I would also suggest to split the algorithm into two, as the part to delete the *current* node is useful as a method on its own.

So then we get this:

```
/* New method for deleting the current node. After deletion the current pointer 
 * will reference the next node if there is one, and otherwise the preceding 
 * one, or if there is none there either, it will be set to null -- the list is
 * empty then.
 */
void MyList::removeCurrent() {
    if (currentPrt == nullptr) return; // Nothing to do
    Node *temp = currentPrt;
    // Rewire the previous and next node so they reference eachother
    if (temp->getBeforePtr() != nullptr) {
        temp->getBeforePtr()->setNextPtr(currentPrt->getNextPtr());
    }
    if (currentPrt->getNextPtr() != nullptr) {
        currentPrt = currentPrt->getNextPtr();
        currentPrt->setBeforePtr(temp->getBeforePtr());
    } else {
        currentPrt = temp->getBeforePtr();
    }
    // Now the temp node is isolated and no more part of the list:
    // It is safe to delete it now.
    delete temp;
}

void MyList::remove(int value) {
    if (currentPrt == nullptr) return; // Nothing to do
    // Go to the right as long as the current node's data is smaller
    while (value > currentPrt->getData() && currentPrt->getNextPtr() != nullptr) {
        currentPrt = currentPrt->getNextPtr();
    }
    // Go to the left as long as the previous node's data is not smaller
    while (currentPrt->getBeforePtr() != nullptr && value <= currentPrt->getBeforePtr()->getData()) {
        currentPrt = currentPrt->getBeforePtr();
    }
    // Arrived at left most node that could have the value we look for.
    // Remove all occurrences
    while (currentPrt != nullptr && value == currentPrt->getData()) {
        removeCurrent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest one thing: Since you assert that the list is ordered when inserting and store the first Node, you never have to search in the descending direction - only ascending.

In your implementation, you modify what you are pointing to, to the last inserted node. I don’t see the benefit of that. Just store the head of the list, and keep the other pointers as local variables. That will make things easier for you.

The bug in remove is probably that you don't reassign next an previous pointers from the successor and the predecessor of the deleted node. Calling delete just frees the memory. That is also why it behaves funny when trying to read unallocated memory.

```
Node* before = nodeToDelete->getBeforePtr();
Node* next = nodeToDelete->getNextPtr();
before->setNextPtr(next);
next->setBeforePtr(before);
delete nodeToDelete;
```

Comment: The assignment doesn't want a head ptr

Comment: The current pointer always points to the number where it is was first created

Comment: It might, if you would assign it in the constructor. Like 
MyList::MyList(Node *currentPrt_) : currentPtr(currnetPrt_) {}

Comment: I was asked to make the constructor to always assign currentPrt to nullptr

Comment: i forgot to update my constructor, I updated it now but nothing changes

Comment: Is it possible to show an example? do I need to create a new Node to hold the values and then reassign them after I delete?

Comment: Get the successor and predecessor of the node to delete and set them as the predecessor and successor of each other, if they are not null. It is your assignment, not mine ;)

Comment: Ok it works but not with 7 or 5, How do you check if a node has a certain value before doing any operations? does my iteration while loop look correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250315/discussion-between-michael-schmitt-and-yusuf-halim).